# /bin/sh: error importing function definition for `some-function'

Tags: bash, shell, function

I encountered this error when updating bash for the CVE-2014-6271 security issue:

```
# yum update bash
Running transaction (shutdown inhibited)
Updating   : bash-4.2.47-4.fc20.x86_64
/bin/sh: error importing function definition for `some-function'
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[edited after 1st comment from: @chepner - thanks!]

/bin/bash allows hyphens in function names, /bin/sh (Bourne shell) does not.
Here, the offending "some-function" had been exported by bash, and
 bash called yum which called /bin/sh which reported the error above.

fix: rename shell functions to not have hyphens

man bash says that bash identifiers may consist:
"only of alphanumeric characters and underscores"

The /bin/sh error is much more explicit:

```
some-function () { :; }
```

sh: `some-function': not a valid identifier

Comment: Note that in `bash`, a hyphen is allowed in a function name, just not in a parameter name.

Comment: @chepner What about an underscore? Is an underscore allowed in a function name and parameter name?

Comment: On my system bash 4 allows function names to have hyphens *but* bash 3 does not — I assume on the OP's system /bin/sh is bash 3, and /bin/bash is bash 4

Answer (score 2):

Change/Fix the function name from `"foo-bar"` to `"foo_bar"`

It is the naming convention that **bash** is ok with, where as **sh** is not.

Replace the "-"(hyphen/dash/minus) with "_"(underscore), and the error gets fixed, and the code works on both **bash** and **sh**